# Can not set hibernate dialect to SQLServer2012Dialect

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

This is my config in `application.properties`:

```
def hibernateVersion="5.2.10.Final"
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: "${hibernateVersion}"
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

But when I debug it shows `SQLServerDialect`.

[image]

How do i change it?

Comment: Do you have any `@Configuration` classes in your project? can you update your answer posting those classes too? Or any other `.properties` file?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: hibernate version is `"5.2.10.Final"`